# How to get CPU usage of all process running in Cocoa application?

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

How to get the CPU usage of the running applications in MAC? I found this solution but it seems so slow as mentioned. I would like to get the CPU usage for each application. This is to determine which application is using high percentage of CPU

[Getting CPU info from Process ID](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3505241/getting-cpu-info-from-process-id)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get CPU percent usage](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6785069/get-cpu-percent-usage)

Comment: I would like to get the CPU usage for each application. This is to determine which application is using high percentage of CPU