# Ruby takes the doubled amount of RAM it should

Tags: ruby

I was trying things out with my homeserver and wrote a little ruby program that fills up the RAM by a given amount. But actually I have to halve the amount of bytes I want to put into the RAM. Am I missing something here or is this a bug?

Here the code:

```
class RAM

  def initialize
    @b = ''
  end

  def fill_ram(size)
    puts 'Choose if you want to set the size in bytes, megabytes or gigabytes.'
    answer = ''
    valid = ['bytes', 'megabytes', 'gigabytes']
    until valid.include?(answer)
      answer = gets.chomp.downcase
      if answer == 'bytes'
        size = size * 0.5
      elsif answer == 'megabytes'
        size = size * 1024 * 1024 * 0.5
      elsif answer == 'gigabytes'
        size = size * 1024 * 1024 * 1024 * 0.5
      else
        puts 'Please choose between bytes, megabytes or gigabyte.'
      end
    end
    size1 = size
    if @b.bytesize != 0
      size1 = size + @b.bytesize
    end
    until @b.bytesize == size1
      @b << '0' * size
    end
    size = 0
  end

  def clear_ram
    exit
  end

  def read_ram
    puts 'At the moment this program fills ' + @b.bytesize.to_s + ' bytes of RAM'
  end

end
```

Just imagine that the `"* 0.5"` at each line wouldn't be there.

I did test it in IRB and just created a new RAM object and filled it with 1000 Megabytes of data. In my case it filled the RAM actually with 2000 Megabytes of data, so I did add the times `0.5` to each line, but that can't be the solution.

Comment: Maybe from interest: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7220896/get-current-ruby-process-memory-usage

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When I run it I get:

```
Choose if you want to set the size in bytes, megabytes or gigabytes.
bytes
At the moment this program fills 512 bytes of RAM
```

I think the problem is the missing check for the encoding.

I ran my test in US-ASCII (One character = 1 Byte).

If you run it in UTF-16 you have an explanation for your problem.

Can you try the following code to check your encoding:

```
p Encoding.default_internal 
p Encoding.default_external
```

---

After reading the comment:

The result of your script depends on the parameter of `RAM.fill_ram`. How do you start your script - and how often do you call `RAM.fill_ram`?

Please provide the full code.

I called my example with

```
r = RAM.new
r.fill_ram(1024)
r.read_ram
```

Comment: Internal: nil and external: UTF-8; the weird thing is: If you remove the time 0.5 at the upper part (so you get the false program code) the actual used memory is twice as much as @b.bytesize - that is the problem and I don't understand why.

Comment: I took a 2nd look: You never mentioned how you call your script. Please provide the full example to see how you use your class.

Comment: Edit will come in a minute.

Comment: I call it exactly like you. The program tells me that it uses 1 GiB of the RAM but I check simultaneously with htop and the RAM usage increases by 2 GiB. So basically the program takes twice as much RAM as I want to. This is why I implemented the "* 0.5" in the bytes/megabytes/gigabytes call. There has to be a variable I forgot or something which is exactly as big as @b.