# How to loop through an array of possible integers, such as from [1,1,1,1] to [1,1,1,2], ... and finally to [6,6,6,6]?

Tags: ruby, iterator

Sometimes I need a way to do this, and wonder if this is a common problem or method and has a name to it:

Such as, we want to iterate through all cases of 4 dice, or iterate through all cases of 20 slots, and each slot can fit in any number from 0 to 50.

So the requirement is given N, the size of the array, such as N = 4, and a "range" such as from 1 to 6, and we do a `Iterator.new(4, 1..6)` and get back:

```
[1, 1, 1, 1]
```

and have a way to do `iterator.next()` and get back

```
[1, 1, 1, 2]
```

and keep on doing `iterator.next()` will get us

```
[1, 1, 1, 6]
```

and the next `iterator.next()` will get us

```
[1, 1, 2, 1]
```

which is like `6 + 1` and it can't hold it, so it resets to `1` and carry over to the next digit.

and `iterator.next()` will finally get to

```
[6, 6, 6, 6]
```

and the next `iterator.next()` will get us

```
false  (or nil)
```

Does this problem have a common name in computer science, and what might be a simple way to do it in Ruby?

Right now I am trying to do it using recursion, and it seems complicated:

```
n = 4
a = 1
b = 6

arr = [a] * 4

def increment_position(arr, a, b, pos)

    return false if (pos >= arr.length)

    arr[-1 - pos] += 1

    if arr[-1 - pos] > b
        arr[-1 - pos] = a
        return increment_position(arr, a, b, pos + 1)
    else
        return arr
    end

end

def get_next_iteration(arr, a, b)
    return increment_position(arr, a, b, 0)
end

loop do
    p arr
    break if !get_next_iteration(arr, a, b)
end
```

**P.S. The solution should not use too much memory, such as just bytes, or kilobytes, or MB.  For example, it should be able to handle `Iterator.new(5, 0..50)` or `Iterator.new(6, 0..50)` easily.**

Comment: You needn't be concerned about the enumerator using too much memory, as it's merely a rule. For example, `arr = [1,2,3]; enum = arr.to_enum; 3.times { puts enum.next } #=> 1 2 3; enum.rewind; arr.replace([4,5,6]); 3.times { puts enum.next } #=> 4 5 6`.

Comment: ...cont. This is @kdole's [suggestion](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7220896/get-current-ruby-process-memory-usage) for determining the memory use of the current Ruby process in bytes:  `def mem_use() \`ps -o rss -p #{$$}\`.strip.split.last.to_i * 1024 end`. Consider the following: `puts mem_use #=> 8232960; 
a = 1_000_000.times.to_a; puts mem_use #=>16498688; enum = a.to_enum; puts mem_use #=> 16498688; 1_000_000.times { enum.next };
puts mem_use #=> 16535552`.

Comment: I was concerned because one answer that would work with small numbers, but with either `product_range_enumerator(5, 0..50)` or `product_range_enumerator(6, 0..50)` it actually hanged my Macbook Pro

Comment: For your specific example, you could write: `s = '-1'; enum = Enumerator.new { |e|; (6**4).times { e << (s = (s.to_i(6)+1).to_s(6); s.each_char.map(&:next).join.rjust(4,'1').split('')) }}`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

AKA as permutations with repetition

```
iterator = (1..6).to_a.repeated_permutation(4)

#demo:
7.times{p iterator.next}

#[1, 1, 1, 1]
#[1, 1, 1, 2]
#[1, 1, 1, 3]
#[1, 1, 1, 4]
#[1, 1, 1, 5]
#[1, 1, 1, 6]
#[1, 1, 2, 1]

iterator2 = (0..50).to_a.repeated_permutation(6) #no problem
```

Answer (score 6):

So, you basically want the cartesian product of a `Range` with itself. That's easy to do:

```
def product_range_enumerator(num, range)
  range.to_a.product(*([range.to_a] * num.pred)).each
end

product_range_enumerator(4, 1..6)
# => #<Enumerator: ...>

enum = product_range_enumerator(4, 1..6)

enum.next
# => [1, 1, 1, 1]

enum.next
# => [1, 1, 1, 2]

# …

enum.next
# => [1, 1, 1, 6]

enum.next
# => [1, 1, 2, 1]

# …

enum.next
# => [6, 6, 6, 6]

enum.next
# StopIteration: iteration reached an end
```

Comment: I will add to the original question that the requirement should be it is not memory intensive.  For example, the example above, with 2 lines: `enum = product_range_enumerator(4, 0..50); sleep 60;`  and the ruby app will show it is using 700MB of memory on Mac OS X's Activity Monitor.  If I change it to `enum = product_range_enumerator(5, 0..50);` it was eating up 20GB of memory and the Macbook wasn't very responsive either (I am using Ruby 2.0.0)

Answer (score 1):

From first principles:

```
def range_enumerator(rng, n)
  Enumerator.new do |e|
    offsets = [*0...n]
    sz = rng.size**n
    arr = [rng.first]*n
    sz.times do
      e << arr
      i = offsets.rindex { |i| arr[i] < rng.last }
      break unless i
      arr[i] += 1
      (i+1...n).each { |j| arr[j] = rng.first } if i < n-1
    end
  end
end

rng = 1..6
n = 4
enum = range_enumerator(rng, n)

count = 0
no_print = (7..rng.size**n-4)
loop do
  e = enum.next
  puts "#{count}: #{e}" unless no_print.cover?(count)
  count += 1
 # puts "count=#{count}"
end
  # 0:    [1, 1, 1, 1]
  # 1:    [1, 1, 1, 2]
  # 2:    [1, 1, 1, 3]
  # 3:    [1, 1, 1, 4]
  # 4:    [1, 1, 1, 5]
  # 5:    [1, 1, 1, 6]
  # 6:    [1, 1, 2, 1]
  # 1293: [6, 6, 6, 4]
  # 1294: [6, 6, 6, 5]
  # 1295: [6, 6, 6, 6]
```

Comment: thanks. what is "first principles"? is this how to write an Enumerator?  That is, have a function that return `Enumerator.new`, which is the new Enumerator object with some logic in it?

Comment: your `no_print.cover?(count)` is an interesting way to skip over a chunk of output

Comment: Many enumerators are produced by Ruby's built-in methods, but you can create you own with the class method [Enumerator::new](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.5/Enumerator.html#method-c-new). That's what I meant by "first principles", but that was a poor choice of words. I should have said, "Create a custom iterator:".