# I need to grab the linux shell {command} into ruby

Tags: ruby

I cannot get the linux current users, memory, hdd usage, cpu load into ruby.

```
require 'socket'
puts "\n"

time = Time.new   
#puts time.day, time.month, time.year
puts "Date " + time.strftime("%d/%m/%Y")+"\t\t\tTime " + time.strftime("%H:%M:%S")+"\t\t\tSystem-Name: " + Socket.gethostname
puts "----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------"
puts "Uptime: " 

#Uptime
uptime = exec "uptime"

#Memory Usage

system (free -m | awk 'NR==2{printf "Memory Usage: %s/%sMB (%.2f%%)\n", $3,$2,$3*100/$2 }')

#Disk usage
df -h | awk '$NF=="/"{printf "Disk Usage: %d/%dGB (%s)\n", $3,$2,$5}'

#Current Users
users | awk '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) {a[$i]++}} END {for(i in a) {print "Current Users:\t"a[i]}}'

#CPU load
top -bn1 | grep load | awk '{printf "CPU Load: %.2f\n", $(NF-2)}'
```

Comment: Please format your questions better in the future.

Answer (score 2):

Use backticks

```
`command`
```

instead of `exec` or `system`.

You might want to read [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18623297/2483313) about the different ways to run system commands and about their differences.

Comment: Isn't this working?  \`(free -m | awk 'NR==2{printf "Memory Usage: %s/%sMB (%.2f%%)\n", $3,$2,$3*100/$2 }')\` Not the surrounding backticks. What error do you get?

Comment: What do you mean by *doesnt work*? Is there an error message? Is something returned that doesn't meet you expectations?

Comment: And what does it return instead? If you don't answer my questions, I will not able to help you...

Comment: i want to get a linux memory usage into a ruby

Answer (score 1):

To grab the stdout and stderr from external commands, you can't use *exec* or *system*, but have to do it like this:

```
 output = `command`
```

Answer (score 0):

First: option should work better, because it returns in the string format.

Second: option is good for some reasons like clear the logs.

```
1) uptime = `uptime`
#OR
2) system("clear")
```

Comment: using awk in ruby ?

Comment: @YeurionmuveeWatcher http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7220896/get-current-ruby-process-memory-usage

and http://www.be9.io/2015/09/21/memory-leak/