# CPU usage OS X interface

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, macos, interface-builder

I want to implement this [Get CPU percent usage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6785069/get-cpu-percent-usage?answertab=active#tab-top) in the simplest way it's possible in XCode with just a windows that shows the CPU percentage usage but I'm newbie in OS X/Cocoa/OBjective-C.
How can I do it?

Answer (score 2):

You should learn the basics of Mac application development. Take a look at [Your First Mac Application](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/General/Conceptual/Mac101/Articles/00_Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010611). It's an Apple tutorial taking you step by step and teaching you how to create Mac applications, from creating the project in Xcode, to polishing your finished application.