# Get detailed iOS CPU usage with different states

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, cpu-usage

How to get CPU usage with different states in IOS for example

**1.Idle**

**2.Running a user space**

**3.Running the kernel/system**

The CPU usage example such as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8223348/ios-get-cpu-usage-from-application/8382889#8382889)  provide total CPU usage only like below.How can I check the different states within the usage?
Any help?

A general usage example available mostly is like below :

```
- (NSString *)cpuUsage
{
   kern_return_t kr;
   task_info_data_t tinfo;
   mach_msg_type_number_t task_info_count;

   task_info_count = TASK_INFO_MAX;
   kr = task_info(mach_task_self(), TASK_BASIC_INFO, (task_info_t)tinfo, &task_info_count);
   if (kr != KERN_SUCCESS)
   {
     return @"NA";
   }

   task_basic_info_t      basic_info;
   thread_array_t         thread_list;
   mach_msg_type_number_t thread_count;
   thread_info_data_t     thinfo;
   mach_msg_type_number_t thread_info_count;
   thread_basic_info_t basic_info_th;
   uint32_t stat_thread = 0; // Mach threads

   basic_info = (task_basic_info_t)tinfo;

   // get threads in the task
   kr = task_threads(mach_task_self(), &thread_list, &thread_count);
   if (kr != KERN_SUCCESS)
   {
      return @"NA";
   }
   if (thread_count > 0)
    stat_thread += thread_count;

   long tot_sec = 0;
   long tot_usec = 0;
   float tot_cpu = 0;
   int j;

   for (j = 0; j < thread_count; j++)
   {
      thread_info_count = THREAD_INFO_MAX;
      kr = thread_info(thread_list[j], THREAD_BASIC_INFO,
                     (thread_info_t)thinfo, &thread_info_count);
      if (kr != KERN_SUCCESS)
      {
          return nil;
      }

      basic_info_th = (thread_basic_info_t)thinfo;

      if (!(basic_info_th->flags & TH_FLAGS_IDLE))
      {
          //This is 0
          tot_sec = tot_sec + basic_info_th->user_time.seconds + basic_info_th->system_time.seconds;

          //This is 0
          tot_usec = tot_usec + basic_info_th->system_time.microseconds + basic_info_th->system_time.microseconds;

          //This is total
          tot_cpu = tot_cpu + basic_info_th->cpu_usage / (float)TH_USAGE_SCALE * 100.0;
      }

  } // for each thread

  kr = vm_deallocate(mach_task_self(), (vm_offset_t)thread_list, thread_count * sizeof(thread_t));
  assert(kr == KERN_SUCCESS);

  return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.2f",tot_cpu];
}
```

**Edit**

I did try the sample mentioned .[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20471920/how-to-get-total-cpu-idle-time-in-objective-c-c-on-os-x/20476923#20476923) but the kernel/system reading always return 0 on actual device.
Is it correct? I am not sure.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44123852/4417447 This seems helpful. Try this.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [iOS - Get CPU usage from application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8223348/ios-get-cpu-usage-from-application)

Answer (score 1):

Try this Objective-C class;

Get current App CPU usage SystemMonitor.cpuUsage()

Get total CPU usage SystemMonitor.usage()

SystemMonitor.h

```
#ifndef SystemMonitor_h
#define SystemMonitor_h
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

typedef struct {
    unsigned int system;
    unsigned int user;
    unsigned int nice;
    unsigned int idle;
} CPUUsage;

@interface SystemMonitor: NSObject
+ (CPUUsage)cpuUsage;
+ (CGFloat)appCpuUsage;
@end
#endif /* SystemMonitor_h */
```

SystemMonitor.m

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "SystemMonitor.h"
#import <sys/sysctl.h>
#import <mach/mach.h>
#import <sys/stat.h>


@implementation SystemMonitor


+ (CPUUsage)cpuUsage {
    kern_return_t kr;
    mach_msg_type_number_t count;
    static host_cpu_load_info_data_t previous_info = {0, 0, 0, 0};
    host_cpu_load_info_data_t info;

    CPUUsage usage = {0, 0, 0, 1};
    count = HOST_CPU_LOAD_INFO_COUNT;

    kr = host_statistics(mach_host_self(), HOST_CPU_LOAD_INFO, (host_info_t)&info, &count);
    if (kr != KERN_SUCCESS) {
        return usage;
    }

    natural_t user   = info.cpu_ticks[CPU_STATE_USER] - previous_info.cpu_ticks[CPU_STATE_USER];
    natural_t nice   = info.cpu_ticks[CPU_STATE_NICE] - previous_info.cpu_ticks[CPU_STATE_NICE];
    natural_t system = info.cpu_ticks[CPU_STATE_SYSTEM] - previous_info.cpu_ticks[CPU_STATE_SYSTEM];
    natural_t idle   = info.cpu_ticks[CPU_STATE_IDLE] - previous_info.cpu_ticks[CPU_STATE_IDLE];
    //natural_t total  = user + nice + system + idle;
    previous_info    = info;

    usage.user = user;
    usage.system = system;
    usage.nice = nice;
    usage.idle = idle;
    //return (user + nice + system) * 100.0 / total;
    return usage;
}

static NSUInteger const kMaxPercent = 100;
+ (CGFloat)appCpuUsage {
    kern_return_t kr;
    task_info_data_t tinfo;
    mach_msg_type_number_t task_info_count;

    task_info_count = TASK_INFO_MAX;
    kr = task_info(mach_task_self(), MACH_TASK_BASIC_INFO, (task_info_t)tinfo, &task_info_count);
    if (kr != KERN_SUCCESS) {
        return -1;
    }

    thread_array_t         thread_list;
    mach_msg_type_number_t thread_count;

    thread_info_data_t     thinfo;
    mach_msg_type_number_t thread_info_count;

    thread_basic_info_t basic_info_th;

    // get threads in the task
    kr = task_threads(mach_task_self(), &thread_list, &thread_count);
    if (kr != KERN_SUCCESS) {
        return -1;
    }

    long total_time     = 0;
    long total_userTime = 0;
    CGFloat total_cpu   = 0;
    int j;

    // for each thread
    for (j = 0; j < (int)thread_count; j++) {
        thread_info_count = THREAD_INFO_MAX;
        kr = thread_info(thread_list[j], THREAD_BASIC_INFO,
                         (thread_info_t)thinfo, &thread_info_count);
        if (kr != KERN_SUCCESS) {
            return -1;
        }

        basic_info_th = (thread_basic_info_t)thinfo;

        if (!(basic_info_th->flags & TH_FLAGS_IDLE)) {
            total_time     = total_time + basic_info_th->user_time.seconds + basic_info_th->system_time.seconds;
            total_userTime = total_userTime + basic_info_th->user_time.microseconds + basic_info_th->system_time.microseconds;
            total_cpu      = total_cpu + basic_info_th->cpu_usage / (float)TH_USAGE_SCALE * kMaxPercent;
        }
    }

    kr = vm_deallocate(mach_task_self(), (vm_offset_t)thread_list, thread_count * sizeof(thread_t));
    assert(kr == KERN_SUCCESS);

    return total_cpu;
}

@end
```