# Getting the CPU load in a scale from 0 to 100%

Tags: macos, cocoa, cpu-usage

I am trying to obtain the CPU load at run time. I am trying [this fantastic answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6795612/316469) but this code gives me the output like this:

```
Core: 0 Usage: 0.120000
Core: 1 Usage: 0.080000
Core: 2 Usage: 0.066667
Core: 3 Usage: 0.070000
```

This is more than I need. How do I get the load in a scale from 0 to 100%, independently of how many cores/CPUS the user has?

OK, I can average these numbers but suppose the average is 0.08. Does it means the load is at 8%? I am not sure about that.

Comment: Make an average then convert it to percent...?

Comment: These numbers come from the insane unix notation that has nothing to do with percent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you read the code you provided, you can see `(@"Core: %u Usage: %f",i,inUse / total)` which can be converted to percent easily with a simple `inUse / total*100`.

And by the way:
[image]

Comment: OK I did that but the numbers don't appear to match the ones reported by Activity Monitor. Are you sure the number coming from this operation is CPU usage in percent?

Comment: By how much they are different @SpaceDog ?

Comment: It was probably some temporary stuff, now it is more or less giving the same values. THANKS.