# How do I access cpu usage information in iOS that I can print out in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, cpu

Is there a way to access and print out the current cpu information for the device? I can't find anything.

Comment: If you mean the CPU usage of your own app check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8223348/ios-get-cpu-usage-from-application. Otherwise check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6785069/get-cpu-percent-usage. Both are in Objective-C but it should be possible to rewrite it.

Comment: This may help you https://stackoverflow.com/a/44134397/6583747