# Overall CPU of real device

Tags: ios, objective-c, cpu

I try to calculate the CPU usage of real device,I need the overall CPU usage value.
Everything I found was for application CPU usage only,is it even possible?
The code I use for the application CPU is from this answer:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/8382889/5293286

Comment: try this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8223348/ios-get-cpu-usage-from-application

Comment: Already saw that,it's for app usage only..Can I somehow make it for overall device CPU?

Comment: have seen this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6785069/get-cpu-percent-usage

Comment: I used this code,but somehow the CPU value I get always increases even when I remove all open apps and get th brightness lower.