# how to compute percentage of CPU used by an app

Tags: c++, c, macos, cpu-usage

I am working on c++ application for Mac OS

There I would like to get percentage of CPU that my app is using.

I have seen getrusage() gives me cpu time used by the app.

```
   timeval userCPU = usage.ru_utime;
   timeval sysCPU = usage.ru_stime;
```

Do both values in the struct store cpu time consumed by the app. Is there any way to get cpu time used by the whole computer?

If not, how can I get the percentage?

Thanks in advance

Comment: See if theres a mac equivalent to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/perfctrs/examples.  Im sure that if they have a task manager there is something that must do the polling.

Comment: Does MacOS has `/proc/stat` file ?

Comment: @KamilCuk nop, it does not

Comment: I thjink look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63166/how-to-determine-cpu-and-memory-consumption-from-inside-a-process)

Comment: I did, but there no method to get cpu for only one app, only total CPU. Any other ideas please ?

Comment: Looks like you need this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8737816/4434329

Comment: no, that way computes cpu load counting all apps not only "mine"

Comment: No ideas anyone?