# NSTask + ps + App Sandbox = error

Tags: objective-c, xcode, sandbox

I'm trying to get process list with bash "ps" command via NSTask on OS X.

When I turn on App Sandbox, application crashes and I got this error in console:

```
14.06.14 2:16:35,426 sandboxd[356]: ([74340]) MyApp(74340) deny forbidden-exec-sugid
```

Is there any solution for this problem?

Fragment of code:

```
NSTask *topTask = [NSTask new];
[topTask setLaunchPath:@"/bin/ps"];
[topTask setArguments:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                       @"-eo", @"pid,pcpu,rss,comm", // output columns
                       nil]];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ps` is a setuid root process and, as such, can't be run from within the sandbox.

What you can have inside the sandbox is `pid, rss, comm` but not `pcpu` from [`[[NSWorkspace sharedWorkspace] runningApplications]`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/AppKit/Reference/NSRunningApplication_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/NSRunningApplication) which will give you an NSArray of [NSRunningApplication](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/AppKit/Reference/NSRunningApplication_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/NSRunningApplication)

You can probably achieve equivalent functionality with [libproc ()](http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/Libc/Libc-594.1.4/darwin/libproc.h) or sysctl.  [Similar question for statistics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/220323/determine-process-info-programmatically-in-darwin-osx)

Depending what you'd like to achieve, here's an interesting link on [observing processes: TN2050](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/technotes/tn2050/_index.html)

Comment: Seems libproc also does not give you CPU information on other processses. `proc_pid_rusage` works perfect to get cpu time, but if you activate the sandbox, you get only the cpu time of your self, regardless wich PID you give :(