# Get information on PID

Tags: c, macos, terminal

I'm trying to get the information on a PID via `c` or `terminal` (ideally I would like to get it both ways, multiple methods)

I have a PID and would like to figure out the time it was claimed. By claimed i mean when a program started using it. Or if a PID was reused, when the latest program that is using it, started to use it.

In Linux what I do is `lstat "/proc/PID_HERE/exe"` or `lstat "/proc/PID_HERE/cmdline"` but I cant figure out how to do this on Mac OS.

Note: I changed from `stat` to `lstat` because a single exe is being used with command line arguments to open multiple instances. So each instance gets a new pid, so I want info on that specific instance, thus on Linux I have to use `lstat`. So any `lstat` equivalent to get pid info on mac os?

Comment: ps -ef | tail -n +1 | awk '{print $5;}' ??

Comment: "C or terminal" is like "French or typewriter". The terminal is an app that can show a window with some text. It's not a language and not a programming environment. You want `bash`.

Comment: Thanks @n.m. i didnt know that! Very useful info. Thanks mfro! I will test that out!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you mean this:

```
ps -p <PID> -o start=
10:22am
```

where you substitute in your PID. The `start=` selects the start time and also suppresses the header line. If you want the header, use

```
ps -p <PID> -o start
STARTED
10:22am
```

Alternatively, you can get the start time formated more fully like this:

```
ps -p <PID> -o lstart=
Fri 26 Sep 10:22:50 2014
```

By the way, if you want a list of the keywords (like `start` and `lstart` above) you can either wade through the manage, or more simply, just give an invalid keyword and it will tell you all the ones it likes :-)

```
ps -o %rubbish
ps: %rubbish: keyword not found
ps: no valid keywords; valid keywords:
%cpu %mem acflag acflg args blocked caught comm command cpu cputime etime f flags gid group ignored
inblk inblock jobc ktrace ktracep lim login logname lstart majflt minflt msgrcv msgsnd ni nice nivcsw
nsignals nsigs nswap nvcsw nwchan oublk oublock p_ru paddr pagein pcpu pending pgid pid pmem ppid pri
pstime putime re rgid rgroup rss ruid ruser sess sig sigmask sl start stat state stime svgid svuid
tdev time tpgid tsess tsiz tt tty ucomm uid upr user usrpri utime vsize vsz wchan wq wqb wql wqr xstat
```

Comment: Wow so so nice thank you!!! Is there any `c` functions that can do this in mac os? Like linux we have `lstat`. The `c` functions run much faster than `bash` stuff because we have to run it then read it.

Comment: Oh also I don't understand what you mean by the "By the way" stuff can you please explain that a little more please.

Comment: To get this information within a program, see here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/220323/determine-process-info-programmatically-in-darwin-osx

Comment: The `by the way` stuff was just mean tfor anyone else reading my answer in case they happened to want the cputime or something else other than the start time, it was just a hint for people wanting a slight variation of what you asked for.

Comment: Thanks man so much agian. So I was thinking ps must use some `c` functions to get that info no? What c functions would be responsible for `lstart=` and `start=`? Is there like source code for this somewhere? :) Ill check that topic thanks man! I think that question answers this question haha thanks bro!