# Process CPU Usage for OS X using libproc.h from Go

Tags: macos, go

I known that excellent replies exist on the subject for questions like:

- [How to determine CPU and memory consumption from inside a process?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63166/how-to-determine-cpu-and-memory-consumption-from-inside-a-process)
- [Determine Process Info Programmatically in Darwin/OSX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/220323/determine-process-info-programmatically-in-darwin-osx)
- [Get CPU percent usage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6785069/get-cpu-percent-usage)

The problem is that I'm trying to use `libproc.h` that defines a `proc_threadinfo` structure (among others) but the field `pth_cpu_usage` is always `0` (see `trheadInfoHandler()` func [here](https://gist.github.com/gsscoder/18e4f83601edf9e26849) to see how I'm using the struct from Go).

Looking at a snippet of Chromium source [here](http://src.chromium.org/viewvc/chrome/trunk/src/base/process/process_metrics_mac.cc?view=markup) (that doesn't use `libproc.h`), I was wondering if using fields from both `proc_threadinfo` and `proc_taskinfo` it could be possible calculate cpu percent usage.

```
proc_threadinfo.pth_user_time; /* user run time */
proc_threadinfo.pth_system_time; /* system run time */

proc_taskinfo.pti_total_user; /* total time */
proc_taskinfo.pti_total_system;
```

**Edit**

<strike>Some **pseudo code** illustrating *the right algorithm* or a suggestion to put me on the right path will be very appreciated.</strike>

Using `/proc` filesystem I think I was able to calculate CPU % usage in **Linux**:

```
func cpuUsageOf(pid int, waitHandler func()) float32 {
    stat1 := procFsStatOf(pid)
    utime1 := stat1.utime // /proc/[pid]/stat field index 13
    stime1 := stat1.stime // /proc/[pid]/stat field index 14
    cputime1 := procFsCpuTimeTotal() // /proc/stat -> sum of cpu values

    waitHandler() // here I wait 1 second

    stat2 := procFsStatOf(pid)
    utime2 := stat2.utime // /proc/[pid]/stat field index 13
    stime2 := stat2.stime // /proc/[pid]/stat field index 14
    cputime2 := procFsCpuTimeTotal() // /proc/stat -> sum of cpu values

    return float32(cpuCount() * ((utime2 + stime2) - (utime1 + stime1)) * 100) / float32(cputime2 - cputime1)
}
```

For **OS X**, do I've to use values from `proc_threadinfo` or `proc_taskinfo`? And where I can find the same values that in Linux I read from `/proc/stat` with (`procFsCpuTimeTotal()`)?

Full code [here](https://github.com/gsscoder/goproc) (as in commit `9e34d3c72bf853ff49ef3970ad6a6c9688e9ba23`); fast link to **OS X** code [here](https://github.com/gsscoder/goproc/blob/master/process_darwin.go).

Comment: Now I'm trying implementing the same thing for Linux following the answer for [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1420426/calculating-cpu-usage-of-a-process-in-linux).

Comment: As you can see in latest question edit: I've done (or I think so) for Linux. Still need some help for OS X.