# How to get hardware details in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift

How to get info of hardware like CPU Model, CPU usage, CPU idle, RAM Details, Storage details etc? I use Xcode 7.1.1 and Swift 2. I want no make app. I tried `UIDevice`, `NSProcessInfo`. I saw several posts but I don't find any solving.

Comment: Can you please show some effort and show us what you've tried so far?

Comment: @try-catch-finally  I tried UIDevice, NSProcessInfo

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Most of this stuff can be revealed with some of the lower level C APIs. This might be a good opportunity for you to write some simple Swift extensions based on them, but you can write C code directly in Swift to get your answers anyway.

I would love to take credit but I'll just link to some answers other people have provided:

- [Process info](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/220323/determine-process-info-programmatically-in-darwin-osx)
- [SystemKit](https://github.com/beltex/SystemKit/blob/master/SystemKit/System.swift)
- [DeviceGuru (in swift!)](https://github.com/InderKumarRathore/DeviceGuru)

Answer (score 5):

Heres HAS' extension that I modified to get the processor and speed from UIDevice. Probably not the best way (all the values are hardcoded) but it works!

```
import Foundation
import NotificationCenter

public extension UIDevice
{
    //Original Author: HAS
    // https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26028918/how-to-determine-the-current-iphone-device-model
    // Modified by Sam Trent

    /**********************************************
    *  getCPUName():
    *     Returns a hardcoded value of the current
    * devices CPU name.
    ***********************************************/
    public func getCPUName() -> String
    {
        var processorNames = Array(CPUinfo().keys)
        return processorNames[0]
    }

    /**********************************************
    *  getCPUSpeed():
    *     Returns a hardcoded value of the current
    * devices CPU speed as specified by Apple.
    ***********************************************/
    public func getCPUSpeed() -> String
    {
        var processorSpeed = Array(CPUinfo().values)
        return processorSpeed[0]
    }

    /**********************************************
    *  CPUinfo:
    *     Returns a dictionary of the name of the
    *  current devices processor and speed.
    ***********************************************/
    private func CPUinfo() -> Dictionary<String, String> {

        #if (arch(i386) || arch(x86_64)) && os(iOS)
        let identifier = ProcessInfo().environment["SIMULATOR_MODEL_IDENTIFIER"]!
        #else

        var systemInfo = utsname()
        uname(&systemInfo)
        let machineMirror = Mirror(reflecting: systemInfo.machine)
        let identifier = machineMirror.children.reduce("") { identifier, element in
        guard let value = element.value as? Int8 , value != 0 else { return identifier }
        return identifier + String(UnicodeScalar(UInt8(value)))
     }
  #endif

  switch identifier {
  case "iPod5,1":                                 return ["A5":"800 MHz"] // underclocked
  case "iPod7,1":                                 return ["A8":"1.4 GHz"]
  case "iPhone3,1", "iPhone3,2", "iPhone3,3":     return ["A4":"800 MHz"] // underclocked
  case "iPhone4,1":                               return ["A5":"800 MHz"] // underclocked
  case "iPhone5,1", "iPhone5,2":                  return ["A6":"1.3 GHz"]
  case "iPhone5,3", "iPhone5,4":                  return ["A6":"1.3 GHz"]
  case "iPhone6,1", "iPhone6,2":                  return ["A7":"1.3 GHz"]
  case "iPhone7,2":                               return ["A8":"1.4 GHz"]
  case "iPhone7,1":                               return ["A8":"1.4 GHz"]
  case "iPhone8,1":                               return ["A9":"1.85 GHz"]
  case "iPhone8,2":                               return ["A9":"1.85 GHz"]
  case "iPhone9,1", "iPhone9,3":                  return ["A10 Fusion":"2.34 GHz"]
  case "iPhone9,2", "iPhone9,4":                  return ["A10 Fusion":"2.34 GHz"]
  case "iPhone8,4":                               return ["A9":"1.85 GHz"]
  case "iPhone10,1", "iPhone10,4":                return ["A11 Bionic":"2.39 GHz"]
  case "iPhone10,2", "iPhone10,5":                return ["A11 Bionic":"2.39 GHz"]
  case "iPhone10,3", "iPhone10,6":                return ["A11 Bionic":"2.39 GHz"]
  case "iPad2,1", "iPad2,2", "iPad2,3", "iPad2,4":return ["A5":"1.0 GHz"]
  case "iPad3,1", "iPad3,2", "iPad3,3":           return ["A5X":"1.0 GHz"]
  case "iPad3,4", "iPad3,5", "iPad3,6":           return ["A6X":"1.4 GHz"]
  case "iPad4,1", "iPad4,2", "iPad4,3":           return ["A7":"1.4 GHz"]
  case "iPad5,3", "iPad5,4":                      return ["A8X":"1.5 GHz"]
  case "iPad6,11", "iPad6,12":                    return ["A9":"1.85 GHz"]
  case "iPad2,5", "iPad2,6", "iPad2,7":           return ["A5":"1.0 GHz"]
  case "iPad4,4", "iPad4,5", "iPad4,6":           return ["A7":"1.3 GHz"]
  case "iPad4,7", "iPad4,8", "iPad4,9":           return ["A7":"1.3 GHz"]
  case "iPad5,1", "iPad5,2":                      return ["A8":"1.5 GHz"]
  case "iPad6,3", "iPad6,4":                      return ["A9X":"2.16 GHz"] // underclocked
  case "iPad6,7", "iPad6,8":                      return ["A9X":"2.24 GHz"]
  case "iPad7,1", "iPad7,2":                      return ["A10X Fusion":"2.34 GHz"]
  case "iPad7,3", "iPad7,4":                      return ["A10X Fusion":"2.34 GHz"]
  case "AppleTV5,3":                              return ["A8":"1.4 GHz"]
  case "AppleTV6,2":                              return ["A10X Fusion":"2.34 GHz"]
  case "AudioAccessory1,1":                       return ["A8":"1.4 GHz"] // clock speed is a guess
  default:                                        return ["N/A":"N/A"]
  }
} 
}
```

You can use it like this:

```
 print(UIDevice.current.getCPUName())
 print(UIDevice.current.getCPUSpeed())
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is the list of updated CPU info from apple. Even though its hardcoded it will work fine until 2021's fall :)

```
    private func CPUinfo() -> Dictionary<String, String> {
    #if targetEnvironment(simulator)
    let identifier = ProcessInfo().environment["SIMULATOR_MODEL_IDENTIFIER"]!
    #else
    
    var systemInfo = utsname()
    uname(&systemInfo)
    let machineMirror = Mirror(reflecting: systemInfo.machine)
    let identifier = machineMirror.children.reduce("") { identifier, element in
        guard let value = element.value as? Int8 , value != 0 else { return identifier }
        return identifier + String(UnicodeScalar(UInt8(value)))
    }
    #endif

 switch identifier {
            //        ipod
        case "iPod5,1":                                 return ["A5":"800 MHz"]
        case "iPod7,1":                                 return ["A8":"1.4 GHz"]
        case "iPod9,1":                                 return ["A10":"1.63 GHz"]
            //            iphone
        case "iPhone3,1", "iPhone3,2", "iPhone3,3":     return ["A4":"800 MHz"]
        case "iPhone4,1":                               return ["A5":"800 MHz"]
        case "iPhone5,1", "iPhone5,2":                  return ["A6":"1.3 GHz"]
        case "iPhone5,3", "iPhone5,4":                  return ["A6":"1.3 GHz"]
        case "iPhone6,1", "iPhone6,2":                  return ["A7":"1.3 GHz"]
        case "iPhone7,2":                               return ["A8":"1.4 GHz"]
        case "iPhone7,1":                               return ["A8":"1.4 GHz"]
        case "iPhone8,1":                               return ["A9":"1.85 GHz"]
        case "iPhone8,2":                               return ["A9":"1.85 GHz"]
        case "iPhone9,1", "iPhone9,3":                  return ["A10":"2.34 GHz"]
        case "iPhone9,2", "iPhone9,4":                  return ["A10":"2.34 GHz"]
        case "iPhone8,4":                               return ["A9":"1.85 GHz"]
        case "iPhone10,1", "iPhone10,4":                return ["A11":"2.39 GHz"]
        case "iPhone10,2", "iPhone10,5":                return ["A11":"2.39 GHz"]
        case "iPhone10,3", "iPhone10,6":                return ["A11":"2.39 GHz"]
        case "iPhone11,2", "iPhone11,4",
            "iPhone11,6",  "iPhone11,8":                return ["A12":"2.5 GHz"]
        case "iPhone12,1","iPhone12,3"
            ,"iPhone12,5":                              return ["A13":"2650 GHz"]
        case "iPhone12,8":                              return ["A13":"2.65 GHz"]
        case "iPhone13,2","iPhone13,1","iPhone13,3":    return ["A14":"2.99 GHz"]
        case "iPhone13,4":                              return ["A14":"3.1 GHz"]
        case "iPhone14,5",
            "iPhone14,4",
            "iPhone14,2",
            "iPhone14,3":                               return ["A15":"2x3.22 GHz"]
            //            ipad
        case "iPad2,1", "iPad2,2", "iPad2,3", "iPad2,4":return ["A5":"1.0 GHz"]
        case "iPad3,1", "iPad3,2", "iPad3,3":           return ["A5X":"1.0 GHz"]
        case "iPad3,4", "iPad3,5", "iPad3,6":           return ["A6X":"1.4 GHz"]
        case "iPad4,1", "iPad4,2", "iPad4,3":           return ["A7":"1.4 GHz"]
        case "iPad5,3", "iPad5,4":                      return ["A8X":"1.5 GHz"]
        case "iPad6,11", "iPad6,12":                    return ["A9":"1.85 GHz"]
        case "iPad2,5", "iPad2,6", "iPad2,7":           return ["A5":"1.0 GHz"]
        case "iPad4,4", "iPad4,5", "iPad4,6":           return ["A7":"1.3 GHz"]
        case "iPad4,7", "iPad4,8", "iPad4,9":           return ["A7":"1.3 GHz"]
        case "iPad5,1", "iPad5,2":                      return ["A8":"1.5 GHz"]
        case "iPad6,3", "iPad6,4":                      return ["A9X":"2.16 GHz"]
        case "iPad6,7", "iPad6,8":                      return ["A9X":"2.24 GHz"]
        case "iPad7,1", "iPad7,2",
            "iPad7,3", "iPad7,4":                       return ["A10X":"2.34 GHz"]
        case "iPad8,1", "iPad8,2",
            "iPad8,3", "iPad8,4":                       return ["A12X":"2.5 GHz"]
        case "iPad8,5", "iPad8,6",
            "iPad8,7", "iPad8,8",
            "iPad8,9", "iPad8,10",
            "iPad8,11", "iPad8,12":                     return ["A12Z":"2.5 GHz"]
        case "iPad13,4",
            "iPad13,5",
            "iPad13,6",
            "iPad13,7",
            "iPad13,8",
            "iPad13,9",
            "iPad13,10",
            "iPad13,11":                                return ["M1":"3.1 GHz"]
            
        default:                                        return ["N/A":"N/A"]
        }
    }
```